# When running as root, how can I make PHP create files with a specific group?

Tags: php, unix, posix

I have a PHP script which runs as root. The script creates some files, and those files should be owned by a specified user and group. I have managed to make the script create the files with the correct owner, however, the group associated with the files is still `root`.

Here's a proof-of-concept for what I'm doing:

```
$userInfo = posix_getpwnam('eric');
posix_initgroups($userInfo['name'], $userInfo['gid']);
posix_setuid($userInfo['uid']);

file_put_contents('test.txt', 'Some content');
```

Then I run it as root:

```
sudo php test.php
```

It creates a file that is tied to the root group:

```
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/    eric)   Gid: (    0/    root)
```

How can I force PHP to create files with the correct `Gid`?

Side note: The script needs to be able to run as root, and running with `su - $user` is not an option in my scenario.

Comment: If your only goal here is to create a file with a different user and group, posix is overkill, just use chown and chgrp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [chgrp()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chgrp.php) after the fact or try the same posix methodology but with the group: [posix_setgid()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.posix-setgid.php).

> The appropriate order of function calls is posix_setgid() first, posix_setuid() last.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `posix_setgid($userInfo['gid']);` to the script after you set the UID should do the trick.

Comment: Before `posix_setuid()`, not after. You have to be root to change your UID or GID, and calling `posix_setuid()` drops root privileges.

Comment: Works either way.

Comment: Doesn't work on my end out of order.  You can't change to any other group unless the process is currently running under superuser.